# In search of a YA book about wrist implants and a city beneath New York

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

New here, I was hoping to track down a book I failed to finish as a kid. I think I probably read it between 1999 and 2007 or so, so it's at least that old.

The protagonist was some sort of street kid, potentially wasn't always but my the beginning of the story he is. He finds himself on the run, and has to cut out his wrist implant with a blade. It's sort of a dystopian future where everyone has an implant which keeps track of money and tracks them.

I remember two specific settings from the story, one being a space station that he goes up to. It was close by, so probably Mars or the Moon. The other I remember a little better, he ends up fleeing into this underground "old New York", which I think even talked about the Brooklyn Bridge, but everything in darkness, and he could hear and sense other people or creatures down there, including something big.

Sorry if that is a bit vague, any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

I saw your post awhile back while looking for, I believe, the same book you are. I posted on the [r/whatsthatbook](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthatbook/comments/u8wvb4/in_search_of_a_ya_book_about_wrist_implants_and_a/) subreddit to see if anyone could help there, and just today, someone did!

It's apparently part of a series called 2099 by John Peel. The specific book I was directed to was [Betrayal](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/723330.Betrayal) which I think is the one with the plot-line that you mention. I'm pretty sure this is the series you and I were looking for, as the covers of the books seem very familiar to me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as quotes from the novel, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).